# How to replicate one year daily data to multiple years taking into account leap years?

Tags: r, time-series, xts, replicate, leap-year

I have 365 daily values from one year. Now I want to replicate these values for the year from 2014 to 2018. If there is a leap year, give February 29 the average value of February 28 and March 01.

How could I do this automatically? This is what I have so far. Thank you very much in advance!

```
library(xts)

set.seed(1)
myday <- seq(1, 365, by = 1)
myvalue <- rnorm(length(myday))
mydata <- data.frame(myday, myvalue)
head(mydata)
#>   myday    myvalue
#> 1     1 -0.6264538
#> 2     2  0.1836433
#> 3     3 -0.8356286
#> 4     4  1.5952808
#> 5     5  0.3295078
#> 6     6 -0.8204684

myyear <- seq(2014, 2018, by = 1)
myyear
#> [1] 2014 2015 2016 2017 2018

leapyearvalue <- 0.5 * (mydata$myvalue[mydata$myday == 28] + mydata$myvalue[mydata$myday == 29])
leapyearvalue
#> [1] -0.9744512

repdata <- coredata(mydata)[rep(seq(nrow(mydata)), length(myyear)), ]
head(repdata)
#>   myday    myvalue
#> 1     1 -0.6264538
#> 2     2  0.1836433
#> 3     3 -0.8356286
#> 4     4  1.5952808
#> 5     5  0.3295078
#> 6     6 -0.8204684
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: Added output for 2014-18.

Here's a function to help with that. Feed in year and day_num (for that year), and it outputs the standard values for that date. I assume that you want April 1 in a leap year to output April 1 from the standard year, which requires shifting from day 92 (in the leap year) to day 91 in a 365-day year.

```
daily_value <- function(year, day_num) {
  leap <- year %in% c(2008, 2012, 2016, 2020, 2024)
  leap_day_val <- 0.5 * (mydata[59,2] + mydata[60,2])
  day_num_adj <- day_num + ifelse(leap & day_num >= 61, -1, 0)
  day_value <- ifelse(leap & day_num == 60, 
                       leap_day_val,
                       mydata[day_num_adj,2])
  day_value
}
```

Tests

```
mydata[59,]
#   myday   myvalue
#59    59 0.5697196
daily_value(2016,59)
#[1] 0.5697196

mydata[59:60,]
#   myday    myvalue
#59    59  0.5697196
#60    60 -0.1350546
mean(c(0.5697196, -0.1350546))
#[1] 0.2173325
daily_value(2016,60)
#[1] 0.2173325

# Day 61 of 2016 was March 1, which is day 60 in years with 365 days
mydata[60,]
#   myday    myvalue
#60    60 -0.1350546
daily_value(2016,61)
#[1] -0.1350546
```

Now, we can apply that to all the days in 2014-18:

```
output <- data.frame(dates = seq.Date(as.Date("2014-01-01"), as.Date("2018-12-31"), 1))
output$day_of_year = lubridate::yday(output$dates)
output$value       = daily_value(lubridate::year(output$dates), output$day_of_year)


subset(output, day_of_year > 58 & day_of_year <= 61)
#          dates day_of_year      value
#59   2014-02-28          59  0.5697196
#60   2014-03-01          60 -0.1350546
#61   2014-03-02          61  2.4016178

#424  2015-02-28          59  0.5697196
#425  2015-03-01          60 -0.1350546
#426  2015-03-02          61  2.4016178

#789  2016-02-28          59  0.5697196
#790  2016-02-29          60  0.2173325  # Leap day gets avg of 2/28 and 3/01
#791  2016-03-01          61 -0.1350546  # Rest of leap year shifted back one day

#1155 2017-02-28          59  0.5697196
#1156 2017-03-01          60 -0.1350546
#1157 2017-03-02          61  2.4016178

#1520 2018-02-28          59  0.5697196
#1521 2018-03-01          60 -0.1350546
#1522 2018-03-02          61  2.4016178
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `leap_year` function from `lubridate`. I have written two functions to automate your task:

```
set.seed(1)
mydata <- rnorm(365)

generate_days <- function(years){
  unlist(sapply(years, function(x) {
  if (lubridate::leap_year(x)){
    1:366} else {
      1:365}
  }))
}

generate_data <- function(years, my_data){ 
  unlist(sapply(years, function(x) {
  if (lubridate::leap_year(x)){
    c(my_data[1:59], mean(my_data[59:60]), my_data[60:365])} else {
      my_data}
}))
}

df <- data.frame(days = generate_days(2014:2018),
                 value = generate_data(2014:2018, mydata))

df[730+60,]
```